# Chrome App - Identity API - Bad client ID NON_NATIVE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I'm getting this weird error and I haven't seen it anywhere else. When I try to call `chrome.identity.getAuthToken`, I get back `undefined` (which means an error occurred) and a `chrome.runtime.lastError` that says `Oauth2: bad client id NON_NATIVE`. I have no idea what that means (I put my Oauth client id into the `manifest.json` just like in the examples) and I haven't seen this error anywhere else.

Comment: When you got your client ID from the API console, did you pick "Installed application" as the application type? The term NON_NATIVE is not appearing in Chromium Code Search, which suggests it's a server error, which suggests it's telling you that you created the client ID incorrectly.

Comment: That was it! I picked a web application under the assumption that Chrome was treating my API call as a web page; I never even saw the Chrome App option as an Installed Application! They should really make that text more clear, but thank you!

Comment: @sowbug Would you mind converting your comment into an answer? So that this question doesn't linger in "unanswered" list.

Comment: OK, done. Typing more characters to get past minimum character-count requirement.

Answer (score 3):

(converted from comment to answer per request from another user)

When you got your client ID from the API console, did you pick "Installed application" as the application type? The term NON_NATIVE is not appearing in Chromium Code Search, which suggests it's a server error, which suggests it's telling you that you created the client ID incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue, solved it by creating new credential with type Chrome App.
i mistakenly created Credential with type web, so i recreated new one.